# Laravel 5.7 firstOrNew doesn't set provided values for new case

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5.7

I am a beginner in Laravel and I'm trying out the `firstOrNew` Eloquent method, as described in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#other-creation-methods).

I have the following table in MySQL:

```sql
SELECT * FROM `ratings`;
+----+-----------+-----------+--------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | realty_id | client_id | rating | created_at          | updated_at          |
+----+-----------+-----------+--------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 |        67 |     29548 |     -1 | 2019-03-23 12:14:32 | 2019-03-23 12:26:57 |
|  2 |        67 |     29549 |      1 | 2019-03-23 12:14:53 | 2019-03-23 12:14:53 |
|  3 |        67 |     29547 |      1 | 2019-03-23 12:20:47 | 2019-03-23 12:20:47 |
|  4 |        67 |     29546 |      1 | 2019-03-23 12:24:47 | 2019-03-23 12:26:52 |
+----+-----------+-----------+--------+---------------------+---------------------+
4 rows in set (0,00 sec)
```

In Laravel, I have my `Rating` model setup as follows:

```php
<?php
namespace App\Models;
use App\Models\BaseModel;

class Rating extends BaseModel
{
    protected $table = 'ratings';

    protected $fillable = [
        'client_id',
        'realty_id',
        'rating',
    ];


    public function realty()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Realty');
    }

    public function client()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Client');
    }

}
```

When I try to retrieve an existing record by passing existing `client_id` and `realty_id`, I get the expected result:

```php
$rating = Rating::firstOrNew([
    'client_id' => 29548,
    'realty_id' => 67,
]);

dd([$rating->client_id, $rating->realty_id]);
/*
Results in
array:2 [▼
  0 => 29548
  1 => 67
]
*/
```

However, when I try the same code with a non-existing `client_id` (say it's his first time submitting a rating), I get `null` for both properties:

```php
$rating = Rating::firstOrNew([
    'client_id' => 29550, // THIS ID IS NOT IN THE `ratings` TABLE
    'realty_id' => 67,
]);

dd([$rating->client_id, $rating->realty_id]);
/*
Results in
array:2 [▼
  0 => null
  1 => null
]
*/
```

If I try to use `firstOrCreate`, instead of `firstOrNew`, I get an Internal Server Error with the following message:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`aptoadmi_aptovc`.`ratings`, CONSTRAINT `realty_ratings_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`realty_id`) REFERENCES `realties` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE) (SQL: insert into `ratings` (`updated_at`, `created_at`) values (2019-04-09 17:44:09, 2019-04-09 17:44:09))

Which is expected, since the values for `client_id` and `realty_id` are not being passed on to the `INSERT` statement.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is that your whole Rating class or is there anything else?

Comment: @ChinLeung that's all.

Comment: Weird I just tried it locally and it's working properly. I'm not able to reproduce your error.

Comment: Can you reproduce this on a fresh installation of Laravel?

Comment: Sorry guys, I ended up working around the problem. @JonasStaudenmeir, no, I did not try a fresh install. I believe it could have something to do with the GraphQL library I'm using (https://github.com/rebing/graphql-laravel), but I can't be sure. Thanks for all the help.